# Someone who disregards his/her own countrymen

Tags: word-request

*I hope this question fits here.*

Imaginary situation:

> Internet user `X` is from `abc` country. User X is of the belief that he/she is an experienced user of a particular Q&A website. He/she is also of the belief that he/she is more educated than other users of his/her country. So, he/she prefers and even advocates that answers should come from people other than his/her country. At times, he/she is rude to people from his country. But he/she is not an anti-national. Why user X does so is unknown. Perhaps, he/she desires to receive holistic opinions, even if that means subscribing to false facts.
>
> <sub>PS: Real life description of user X is not considered as of now</sub>

**Question: Which word(s) can be used to describe *user X*?**

---

I did try to look for answers here before asking. I looked for answers in [this question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56944/what-do-you-call-a-person-who-is-regionally-biased)

Some words here are:

1. **Chauvinism** is a form of extreme patriotism and nationalism, a fervent faith in national excellence and glory.
2. **Xenophobia** is the fear or hatred of that which is perceived to be foreign or strange.
3. **Chauvinism** is a form of extreme patriotism and nationalism and a belief in national superiority and glory.
4. **Prejudice** is an affective feeling towards a person based on their perceived group membership. *This words seems good for the situation*
5. If you say that someone is **insular**, you are being critical of them because they are unwilling to meet new people or to consider new ideas. *I think this word fits as well*
6. **Jingoism** is nationalism in the form of aggressive and proactive foreign policy, such as a country's advocacy for the use of threats or actual force, as opposed to peaceful relations, in efforts to safeguard what it perceives as its national interests.
7. **Bigot:** a person who has strong, unreasonable beliefs and who does not like other people who have different beliefs or a different way of life.

Most of these words don't fit for user X, I think. (I could be wrong)

---

*Disclaimer: I don't intend to hurt anyone's sentiment by this question. The situation described is purely fictional*

Comment: It might be a combination of the words "oikos" and "mis"

Comment: ***Turncoat***?

Answer (score 1):

Prejudice can be *for or against* the perceived members of a group. This allows the unusual case of being against *one’s own* group, as your user X is.

Chauvinism, xenophobia, insularism, jingoism and bigotry all have a common thread of feeling your own group is superior.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @StephenS. Keeping `user X` aside, are there words for **someone who disregards his/her own countrymen**? Or is that too ambitious or broad?

Comment: @SeverusSnape Maybe “reverse chauvinism”? I can’t think of a single word for it, but I’ve also never needed one.

Comment: Sometimes it is good to disagree with many of your "countrymen", for example in Nazi Germany, and, arguably, in any democracy. if a country or society has undemocratic, backward, or cruel tendencies, it is good for them to be opposed.

Answer (score 1):

The unsubstantiated belief that you are smarter than everyone else in your country could be *arrogance* or *vanity*.
The belief that other people in your country aren't worth listening to could be *snobbery* or *prejudice*.
(In all of these cases, the words don't specify that it's against people in your own country but they are appropriate words to use.)
I would need more context to know if it was appropriate to call them *elitist,* because that's an ideology.